# WordPress is_page conditional causes blank page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, conditional-statements, slideshow

I'm trying to use the is_page conditional tag to create a slider that displays different sets of images depending on the page.

Below I've created an example of the code I'm using. All I'm getting back is a blank page and I'm really not sure why. Everything I've looked at on Google tells me my Syntax is correct (At least from what I can tell).

I am using the is_page tag before the loop in WordPress so that shouldn't effect it as far as I'm aware. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I tried placing `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` just before the loop too, but it had no effect.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EXAMPLE:

```
<div id="container">    

   <?php if (is_page('123') || is_page('356')){ ?> // check page, if any are true display image
        <a href="#"><img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/image1.jpg" width="650" /></a>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php if (is_page('123') || is_page('356') || is_page('638') || is_page('1199')){ ?> // check page, if any are true display image
      <a href="#"><img alt="" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/image2.jpg" width="650" /> </a>
   <?php } ?>

</div>
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:

```
<?php
// THIS GIVES US SOME OPTIONS FOR STYLING THE ADMIN AREA
function custom_design() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
           #wphead{background:#592222}
           #footer{background:#592222}
           #footer-upgrade{background:#592222}
           textarea {white-space:nowrap;overflow:scroll;}
         </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_design');
?>
```

It seems this piece of code in my functions.php was causing the error. The CSS "whitespace:nowrap" was breaking any new template pages I was making. Totally bizarre. Never seen CSS do that before, at least not to that extent.

Sorry for wasting your time guys, thank you for the help. At least I know I wasn't going crazy now.

:)

Comment: and if you remove this section the page works again?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Are you sure if this is the only issue?? if you remove is_page() function does page work again?

Comment: Cheers, seems it was something else. Have added the explanation above. If anyone knows why it was causing it, I'd like to know :)